# Calling clear on a vector immediately after construction?

Tags: c++, std

I've seen some C++ code like this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.clear();
vec.push_back(42);
```

What is the purpose (if any) of clearing the vector right after creating it?

Comment: There's no purpose; the clear is redundant and the compiler could optimize it out

Comment: I guess it could be something related to the specific implementation. However even in this case this program (if no other lines in between) has no sense.

Comment: It might still be legacy from when it was an output argument. Or simply a programmer not familiar enough with the class

Answer (score 7):

It serves no purpose - the vector is already created in an empty state.

If you are lucky, your compiler will optimize away this redundant call entirely - recent versions of both gcc and clang do [exactly that](https://godbolt.org/z/nQNTNu).